# 3 column flow layout vs table layout

Tags: html, css

I've noticed there are quite a few 3 column flow layouts that people use.  What isn't clear to me is, how is this better than simply using a table with 3 columns and one row?  Can you tell me the pros / cons of using a flow layout for this situation vs. a table layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Tables vs. CSS" has been a debate for about a decade now. Most folks these days will acknowledge that for laying out the page, CSS is typically the better way to go most of the time. In general, CSS layouts tend to be more semantic, easier to maintain (layout is in the CSS file rather than embedded in the HTML) and can offer a better avenue for 'responsive design' which is the new buzzword of the day:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste to rich text editor or create alternative css for printing.

Comment: Thanks, not sure I get what you're saying. Can you expand please?

Comment: I think maybe he is saying to try those things with tables and see the issues you run into?

Comment: I got what he's saying -- since one is controlling appearance with the CSS, one can therefore better control printing by using an alternate style in the CSS (and not be stuck with html layout)

Answer (score 1):

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/

All you gotta do is google. It is quite old topic.

Basically Table create more clutter in HTML along with some other limitation.

Link above is detailed comparison.

Comment: Link above also gives you example of HTML5 which is way cleaner approach to even using DIV.

Answer (score 1):

Table layouts were what people did in the 90s before CSS was available. DA explained it well. With CSS and divs etc, you can completely rearrange your layout if you want, from your CSS file. If you are using tables you would have to edit the HTML on every page to change your layout. Tables add so much HTML clutter. What looks nicer: `<div></div>` or `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>` ?

The only handy thing that tables can do for layout is that cells in the same row are automatically the same size.